# grails 3 (spring-boot) - how to configure hibernate second level cache

Tags: hibernate, grails, spring-boot, grails-3.0

When trying to use ehcache as hibernate second level cache, I get following exception:
org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given

I tried to configure it in application.yml:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        cache:
          region:
            factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
```

and:

```
grails:
    hibernate:
      cache:
        use_second_level_cache: true
        provider_class: net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider
        region:
          factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
```

but none of these seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

The latter should work if you remove the `grails` top level config since Grails looks for 'hibernate.blah' not 'grails.hibernate.blah':

```
  hibernate:
      cache:
        use_second_level_cache: true
        provider_class: net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider
      region:
         factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
```

Comment: I am a bit confused. I generated a new app with version 3.0.1 and I see in the application.yml: - grails> hibernate> cache> queries: false

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `grails` before `hibernate`. Grails is expecting the structure of region to be under the cache.

> Remember tabs are important in yml files

So the code should look something like this:

```
hibernate:
cache:
    queries: false
    use_second_level_cache: true
    use_query_cache: false
    region:
        factory_class: 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a late answer but may help someone in the future.

Try adding this dependency in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and then in application.yml:

```
spring:
    jpa:
        properties:
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
            hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
```